# react setState update array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I have the below code where I am trying to update setState with few properties modified in array of objects

```
onClick(index) {
    let tmp = this.state.daysOfWeek;
    tmp[index].active = !tmp[index].active;
    if (tmp[index].active === true) {
      tmp[index].className = "selectedDay";
    } else {
      tmp[index].className = "remSelectedDay";
    }

    this.setState({ daysOfWeek: [...this.state.daysOfWeek, tmp]})
  }
```

Here tmp is modified array of objects.  If I use spread operator then the arry of objects are concatinated wiht tmp.

How could I update the current state with array of objects ?

Comment: Loop through them using `map` and then return updated array.

Comment: How your state / days of week looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `map` and the functional form of `setState` will allow you to correctly update the array without directly modifying the state:

```
onClick(index){
  this.setState(state => {
    return {
      daysOfWeek: state.daysOfWeek.map((day, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return {
            ...day,
            active: !day.active,
            className: day.active ? 'remSelectedDay' : 'selectedDay'
          }
        }
        return day;
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick (index) {
    const { daysOfWeek } = this.state        // for example: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index = 1
    this.setState({
        daysOfWeek: [
            ...daysOfWeek.slice(0, index),               // [1]
            {
                ...daysOfWeek[index],                    // this is 2
                active: !daysOfWeek[index],
                className: daysOfWeek[index] ? 'selectedDay' : 'remSelectedDay'
            },
            ...daysOfWeek.slice(index + 1)               // [3, 4, 5]
        ]
    })
}
```