# Update object across array of objects using setState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My question relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026192/react-setstate-update-array-of-objects) but the issue here that I must relay on object properties and I want to update just ONE object. If I am using `map` it updates all objects in my array of objects. Its structure is:

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      itemNames: ['aaa','xxx'],
      removed: [],
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      itemNames: ['yyy', 'xxx'],
      removed: [],
      ...
    },
    ...
]
```

My logic is: I look for item name across itemNames, if it exists in state - remove it from first object occurance and add it to removed property of this object. I managed to do it with map, but then it does it for every object that has given item name.

```
function filterByItemName(itemName) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    arr: prevState.arr.map(item) => {
      if (item.itemNames.includes(itemName)) {
        return {
          ...item,
          removed: [...item.removed, itemName],
          itemNames: removeFirstFoundElement(item.itemNames, itemName),
        };
      }
      return item;
    }),
  }));
}
```

The following code works in a way that it finds ALL objects with given itemName - but I would like to change just first case... After calling `filterByItemName('xxx')` I want it to be:

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      itemNames: ['aaa'],
      removed: ['xxx],
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      itemNames: ['yyy', 'xxx'],
      removed: [],
      ...
    },
    ...
]
```

While now it is as follows:

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      itemNames: ['aaa'],
      removed: ['xxx],
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      itemNames: ['yyy'],
      removed: ['xxx'],
      ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Everything is there - how it works now and how it should as well...

Comment: Trying to understand what you're trying to do - you want to remove the first found element and update all the other matching ones?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set a `shouldInsert` flag to check if you've already inserted once or not. Here is my approach. It would be easier if you could share some `codesandbox` link here.

```
function filterByItemName(itemName) {
  let shouldInsert = true;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    arr: prevState.arr.map(item) => {
      const found = item.itemNames.includes(itemName);
      if (found && shouldInsert) {
        shouldInsert = false;
        return {
          ...item,
          removed: [...item.removed, itemName],
          itemNames: removeFirstFoundElement(item.itemNames, itemName),
        };
      }
      return item;
    }),
  }));
}
```